# Why does this parent class setter call use type(self) rather than self?

Tags: python, super, python-class

[Python @property inheritance the right way](https://gist.github.com/Susensio/979259559e2bebcd0273f1a95d7c1e79) explains how to call the parent setter.

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        assert self._value is not None
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        self._value = new_value


class Integer(Number):
    @property
    def value(self):
        return super().value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, new_value):
        _value = int(new_value)
        super(Integer, type(self)).value.fset(self, _value) # <----- OK with using type(self)
        # super(Integer, self).value.fset(self, _value)     # <----- Assert error with self
        
i = Integer()
i.value = 1             # cause assertion error with "super(Integer, self)"
print(i.value)
```

## Problem

With `super(Integer, type(self)).value.fset(self, _value)` , `i.value = 1`  invokes the setter as expected.

With `super(Integer, self).value.fset(self, _value)`,  `i.value = 1`  invokes the getter instead of the setter, hence causing the assertion error.

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-2c57a07c128d> in <module>
     35 
     36 i = Integer()
---> 37 i.value = 1
     38 print(i.value)

<ipython-input-8-2c57a07c128d> in value(self, new_value)
     32         _value = int(new_value)
     33         #super(Integer, type(self)).value.fset(self, _value)
---> 34         super(Integer, self).value.fset(self, _value)
     35 
     36 i = Integer()

<ipython-input-8-2c57a07c128d> in value(self)
     10     @property
     11     def value(self):
---> 12         assert self._value is not None
     13         return self._value
```

## Question

Please help understand why `super(Integer, self).value.fset(self, _value)` goes to the **getter instead of the setter** although calling `fset`. Reading the documents and articles, it looks to me passing the object `self` instead of type/class `type(self)` is the correct way to access the method bound to the instance itself, but it does not work.

[super([type[, object-or-type]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

> The object-or-type determines the method resolution order to be
> searched. The search starts from the class right after the type.
>
> For example, if **mro** of object-or-type is D -> B -> C -> A ->
> object and the value of type is B, then super() searches C -> A ->
> object.
>
> The **mro** attribute of the object-or-type lists the method
> resolution search order used by both getattr() and super(). The
> attribute is dynamic and can change whenever the inheritance hierarchy
> is updated.

[Supercharge Your Classes With Python super()](https://realpython.com/python-super/#a-super-deep-dive)

> In Python 3, the super(Square, self) call is equivalent to the
> parameterless super() call. The first parameter refers to the subclass
> Square, while the second parameter refers to a Square object which, in
> this case, is self. You can call super() with other classes as well:
>
> ```
>     def surface_area(self):
>         face_area = super(Square, self).area()
>         return face_area * 6
>
>     def volume(self):
>         face_area = super(Square, self).area()
>         return face_area * self.length
> ```
>
> What about **the second parameter**? Remember, this is an object that is
> an instance of the class used as the first parameter. For an example,
> isinstance(Cube, Square) must return True.
>
> **By including an instantiated object, super() returns a bound method: a
> method that is bound to the object**, which gives the method the
> object’s context such as any instance attributes. If this parameter is
> not included, the method returned is just a function, unassociated
> with an object’s context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `super(Integer, self).value.fset(self, _value)` (or the simpler equivalent, `super().value.fset(self, _value)`) occurs before you even get to the `fset`. The descriptor protocol is engaged on all lookups on an instance, cause it to invoke the getter simply by doing `super(Integer, self).value` (or `super().value`). That's why your inherited getter works in the first place; it invoked the `property` descriptor, and got the value produced by it.

In order to bypass the descriptor protocol (more precisely, move from instance to class level invocation, where `property`s do nothing special in the class level scenario), you need to perform the lookup on the class itself, not an instance of it. `super(Integer, type(self))` invokes the form of `super` that returns a `super` object bound at the class level, not the instance level, allowing you to retrieve the raw descriptor itself, rather than *invoking* the descriptor and getting the value it produces. Once you have the raw descriptor, you can access and invoke the `fset` function attached to it.

This is the same issue you have when `super` *isn't* involved. If you have an instance of `Number`, and want to directly access the `fset` function (rather than invoking it implicitly via assignment), you have to do:

```
num = Number()
type(num).value.fset(num, 1)
```

because doing:

```
num.value.fset(num, 1)
```

fails when you retrieve `num.value` (getting the `None` the getter produces), then try to look up `fset` on `None`.

Comment: "super(Integer, type(self)) invokes the form of super that returns a super object bound at the class level, not the instance level, allowing you to retrieve the raw descriptor itself, rather than invoking the descriptor and getting the value it produces." - well, it still invokes the descriptor protocol, but the class version of the descriptor protocol, not the instance version. This matters for something like `@classmethod`, but for a property, lookup on a class just returns the property object.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Yeah, I didn't want to get into the weeds on this in the body of the main answer. There's also the case where the *instance* level descriptor protocol is still invoked *if* the class's metaclass defines such a descriptor (because all classes are themselves instances of their metaclass; it's turtles all the way down). I added a parenthetical about your note.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thanks a lot for the answer and sorry for having not accepted yet as I need time to digest the content and the descriptor protocol.